# What are the requirements for foreigners to join the RAAF as a fighter pilot?

Tags: military, fighter, pilots, career, australia

What are the requirements for a foreigner — I'm from Cyprus — to join the [Royal Australian Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Australian_Air_Force) (RAAF) to become a fighter pilot?

Comment: thats hardly all the requirements is it? and ive looked there already

Comment: Did you tried contacting them ? 
https://www.defencejobs.gov.au/airforce/contact/default.aspx?service=3

Comment: That's simply the recruiter contact form. I'm sure they'll have a long list of questions & requirements to follow up with. I think @Antzi's point was that you'll need to contact them to get all the requirements.

Comment: Are you asking about the special requirements for foreigners, or just all the requirements?

Answer (score 7):

Only citizens of a country can apply in the government jobs (including armed forces) of that country. There can be some exceptions but I hardly doubt that a foreigner can be hired or trained for any position in military which has access to classified information. Being a fighter pilot even has more restrictions.

Royal Australian Air Force [does not hire any foreigner](http://www.defencejobs.gov.au/airforce/jobs/Pilot/):

> **Can I apply if I am not an Australia Citizen?**
>
> To be eligible to join the Air Force, you must be an Australian
>   Citizen.

According to Recruitment Centre of Australian Defence Force, [this page lists the proofs required for citizenship](http://www.defencejobs.gov.au/recruitmentCentre/canIJoin/citizenship/).

Comment: It is not unusual for permanent residents to be able to be hired for at least some jobs. For instance, you can enlist in the US military as a permanent resident; you must become a citizen to become an officer, and some branches make you become a citizen to reenlist, but you can become a citizen much more easily once joining the military. Australia seems more restrictive of permanent residents, but they can still be hired under some circumstances. They may not qualify to be a *pilot*, but they can be hired by the RAAD.

Comment: Also, foreigners can certainly qualify to join if they first become naturalized citizens. They're not really "foreigners" after becoming naturalized, but there is a path from foreigner to air force pilot.

Comment: @cpast The article I referenced does talk about permanent residents. And naturalized citizens are not foreigners, they **are** citizens.

Comment: It might be true for the RAAF but it isn't in general true around the world. Foreign residents used to be impressed into the US Army by the draft during the Vietnam war (and some are still required to join the Selective Service List) and certainly many commonwealth citizens join the British forces today by choice. OP can join the (British) RAF if she/he wishes.

Comment: Further, there is a large difference between joining the RAAF and being an RAAF fighter pilot. Numbers from the USAF, but I expect the RAAF isn't much different: Currently 326,855 active duty. 12,568 pilots (of all aircraft types). I'd guesstimate that no more than 1/3 of those pilots fly fighter jets. So maybe 1% of all active duty personnel fly fighters.  USAF Demographics, 2021 - https://www.afpc.af.mil/About/Air-Force-Demographics/